# Oracle SQL- Update Query with Case Statement Missing Keyword Error

Tags: sql, string, oracle, case

I'm extremely new to SQL (started learning 3 days ago), so I'm assuming I have some horrendous syntax errors in my code.

I've been at it since yesterday, trying to create an update query that uses cases to modify the `value` column based on the following conditions:

1. When `value` contains the letter 'a', make value uppercase.
2. When `value` contains the letter 'd', but doesn't contain the letter 'a', make `value` lowercase.
3. When `value` doesn't meet the conditions above, change the first and last letters from `value` to 1 and 2.

I have tried to do this a bunch of different ways, but I always end up with some kind of error. This code returns Missing Keyword Error:

```
UPDATE t1  
SET value = 
CASE   WHEN value LIKE '%a%' THEN SET value = UPPER(value)   
       WHEN value LIKE '%d%' AND value NOT LIKE '%a' THEN SET value = LOWER(value)   
       ELSE REPLACE(value,'_%','1') AND REPLACE(value,'%_','2') 
END
Where value IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: It's worth noting that because case expressions do short circuiting of the logic (i.e. it stops processing at the first condition that is satisfied), by the time you reach the `when value like '%d%' ...` condition, you automatically know that there are no `a`s present in the string (otherwise the first condition in the case expression would have been met). So, your second condition could just be `when value like '%d%' then lower(value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE` returns a value so you don't need the `SET` there. `AND` is a conditional operator, it's not for running commands together.

`REPLACE()` does not work the way you're trying to use it. It takes literals not wildcards. So unless `value` starts and finishes with underscores, `'_%'` the command won't change anything. Instead of `REPLACE()` I suggest you use SUBSTR() and concatenate the replacement characters.

```
UPDATE t1  
SET value = 
    CASE   WHEN value LIKE '%a%' THEN UPPER(value)   
           WHEN value LIKE '%d%' AND value NOT LIKE '%a' THEN LOWER(value)   
           ELSE '1'||substr(value, 2, length(value)-2) ||'2' 
    END
Where value IS NOT NULL;
```

Alternatively, you could use the regular expression replace function

```
ELSE regexp_replace(value, '^(.)(.*)(.)$', '1\22'
```

However, this has slightly different output when the length of `value` is 1.

Answer (score 0):

there are many `syntex` error in `Case statment` you cant use again `SET` `operation` and you cant use `separated replace`

change

1.`SET value = UPPER(value)` to  `UPPER(value)`
2.`SET value = LOWER(value)` to `LOWER(value)` and 
3. `remove` second`replace` like this

```
UPDATE t1  
SET value = 
CASE   WHEN value LIKE '%a%' THEN SET UPPER(value)   
       WHEN value LIKE '%d%' AND value NOT LIKE '%a' THEN LOWER(value)   
       ELSE REAPLACE(REPLACE(value,'_%','1'),'%_',2)
END
Where value IS NOT NULL;
```